# increment '+' with optional chaining

Tags: angular

I have an error in typescript: **Expression expected.ts(1109)**.

[image]

```
export class Order {

  id?: number;
  orderName?: string;
  price?: number;
  image?: string;
  description?: string;
  dateCreated?: Date;
  dateUpdated?: Date;

}


export class CartOrder {

  id?: number;
  orderName?: string;
  price?: number;
  image?: string;
  quantity?: number;


  constructor(order: Order){
    this.id = order.id
    this.orderName = order.orderName
    this.price = order.price
    this.image = order.image
    this.quantity = 1;
  }
}
```

when I remove '?' from existsOrder?.quantity?++ to be existsOrder?.quantity++ , I am getting error also:
**Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
The operand of an increment or decrement operator may not be an optional property access.ts(2777)
(property) CartOrder.quantity?: number | undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check for the quantity in the `if` before incrementing

```
if (isExists && existsOrder?.quantity) {
  existsOrder.quantity++;
}
```